# React / DRF: how do I resolve this 401 error on sign in based on my code?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am creating a book review site using React for the frontend and a Django Rest Framework api to connect to the database. It is deployed using Heroku and the database is using ElephantSQL. This is my first project using React, so there may be a few errors...

The problem I am having is that when I sign in, I get a 401 error but do not understand why within my code...
[401 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vUEz.png)
[additional errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lNMC.png)

I need it to, once a user has logged in, go back to the homepage and the navbar elements of "Sign In" and "Sign Up" are replaced by the signed in user's username.

The code for the sign in page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import styles from "../../styles/SignUpForm.module.css";
import appStyles from "../../App.module.css";

import { Form, Button, Image, Col, Row, Container, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSetCurrentUser } from "../../contexts/CurrentUserContext";

const SignInForm = () => {
    const setCurrentUser = useSetCurrentUser();
  
    const [signInData, setSignInData] = useState({
      username: "",
      password: "",
    });
    const { username, password } = signInData;
  
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("/dj-rest-auth/login/", signInData);
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.user)
        setCurrentUser(data.user);
        history.goBack();
      } catch (err) {
        setErrors(err.response?.data);
      }
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setSignInData({
          ...signInData,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
      };
    
    return (
        <Row className={styles.Row}>
            <Col md={6}
            className={`my-auto d-none d-md-block p-2 ${styles.SignInCol}`}>
                <Image
                    className={`${appStyles.FillerImage}`}
                    src={
                        "https://codeinstitute.s3.amazonaws.com/AdvancedReact/hero2.jpg"
                    }
                />
            </Col>
            <Col className="my-auto py-2 p-md-2" md={6}>
                <Container className={`${appStyles.Content} p-4 `}>
                    <h1 className={styles.Header}>Sign In</h1>
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="username">
                            <Form.Label className="d-none">Username</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Username"
                                name="username"
                                className={styles.Input}
                                value={username}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                        </Form.Group>
                        {errors.username?.map((message, idx) => (
                            <Alert variant="warning" key={idx}>
                                {message}
                            </Alert>
                        ))}
                        <Form.Group controlId="password">
                            <Form.Label className="d-none">Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            className={styles.Input}
                            value={password}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        </Form.Group>
                        {errors.password?.map((message, idx) => (
                            <Alert variant="warning" key={idx}>
                                {message}
                            </Alert>
                        ))}
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Sign In
                        </Button>
                        {errors.non_field_errors?.map((message, idx) => (
                            <Alert key={idx} variant="warning" className="mt-3">
                                {message}
                            </Alert>
                        ))}
                    </Form>
                </Container>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
};

export default SignInForm;
```

CurrentUserContext.js code:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { axiosRes } from "../api/axiosDefaults";

export const CurrentUserContext = createContext();
export const SetCurrentUserContext = createContext();

export const useCurrentUser = () => useContext(CurrentUserContext);
export const useSetCurrentUser = () => useContext(SetCurrentUserContext);

export const CurrentUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  const handleMount = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosRes.get("dj-rest-auth/user/");
      setCurrentUser(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleMount();
  }, []);

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>
      <SetCurrentUserContext.Provider value={setCurrentUser}>
        {children}
      </SetCurrentUserContext.Provider>
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Any help or guidance would be great!

I know the data is being passed to the backend api and that the user log in credentials are correct.

I am following a tutorial and it was working up until I moved the CurrentUserContext to it's own file, but even going back hasn't helped.

Comment: What does the `/dj-rest-auth/login/` endpoint look like on the backend?

Comment: please first read about https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html documentation and then move forward